# Css button text issue

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS button for my site which used to be full with the text in the very middle of it, but now the text is at the bottom and the button is smaller. Other people have had access to my root folder to make amendments and i dont know what they've done.

```
.button
{
    display: inline;
    margin-top: 2em;
    padding: 1em 2em 1em 2em;
    background: #8dc63f;
    letter-spacing: 0.20em;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 0.90em;
    color: #FFF;
}

.button:before
{
}
```

Comment: Are you able to post a small picture of the button?

Comment: Mike your CSS is displaying the correct output http://jsfiddle.net/Z2qfZ/ .Possibility is that you are overriding this CSS somewhere else.

Comment: Maybe a browser issue, what are you using?

Comment: Its sorted guys, cheers for the responses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try: `display: inline-block`

That should sort it.

Comment: This sorted it :) Thanks and thanks everyone for their answers

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: block;` and  `text-align:center;`

```
    .button{
    display: block;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top: 2em;
    padding: 1em;
    background: #8dc63f;
    letter-spacing: 0.20em;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 0.90em;
    color: #FFF;
   }
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/uxuLAhA/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :-

```
text-align: center;
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
```

Hope it will help you.